# Why does this error appear in spite of correct class?

Tags: java, spring

This is the error message:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is
>   org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Could not set
>   property 'nWriteDate' of 'class com.tj.notice.model.Notice1' with
>   value '2018-02-12 15:17:54.0' Cause:
>   org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no setter
>   for property named 'nWriteDate' in 'class com.tj.notice.model.Notice1'

Class `Notice1`:

```
package com.tj.notice.model;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Notice1 {

    private int nIdx;
    private String aID;
    private String nTitle;
    private String nContent;
    private Timestamp nWritedate;
    private int startRow;
    private int endRow;
    public int getnIdx() {
        return nIdx;
    }
    public void setnIdx(int nIdx) {
        this.nIdx = nIdx;
    }
    public String getaID() {
        return aID;
    }
    public void setaID(String aID) {
        this.aID = aID;
    }
    public String getnTitle() {
        return nTitle;
    }
    public void setnTitle(String nTitle) {
        this.nTitle = nTitle;
    }
    public String getnContent() {
        return nContent;
    }
    public void setnContent(String nContent) {
        this.nContent = nContent;
    }
    public Timestamp getnWritedate() {
        return nWritedate;
    }
    public void setnWritedate(Timestamp nWritedate) {
        this.nWritedate = nWritedate;
    }
    public int getStartRow() {
        return startRow;
    }
    public void setStartRow(int startRow) {
        this.startRow = startRow;
    }
    public int getEndRow() {
        return endRow;
    }
    public void setEndRow(int endRow) {
        this.endRow = endRow;
    }   
}
```

Why does this error appear in spite of correct class?

Comment: Java is case sensitive, so you have to be carefull. From error message it seems somewhere else it is expected it is `nWriteDate`, but you have `nWritedate` in code and also proper setter is `setNWritedate` not `setnWritedate`... Use the naming consistently...

Answer (score 3):

When you meet an exception, be patient to it. It says "There is no setter for property named 'nWriteDate' in 'class com.tj.notice.model.Notice1'".

You need to change

```
public Timestamp getnWritedate() {
        return nWritedate;
    }
    public void setnWritedate(Timestamp nWritedate) {
        this.nWritedate = nWritedate;
    }
```

to

```
public Timestamp getNWritedate() {
        return nWritedate;
    }
    public void setNWritedate(Timestamp nWritedate) {
        this.nWritedate = nWritedate;
    }
```

Often you can avoid this kind of error by generate getter and setter by IDE, such as eclipse, intellij.